# Should I get a lens repaired or buy a new one?

Tags: lens, repair

I have a [28-135mm Canon lens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006I53S) that I picked up a few years ago for $200. The zoom has started sticking in the last couple of days. It still focuses fine, but can be annoying trying to zoom in/out (sticks in the middle). Should I look for a replacement or a repair?

Answer (score 12):

Two ways to look at it:

1. This is the perfect excuse to upgrade to a newer and better lens.
2. You really love this lens and that is the one you truly want. Fix it. Generally charges for this should be around $150 which is less costly than a new one.

Comment: I'm with Itai on this one.